# Theil–Sen estimator in R with more than one variable?

Tags: r, estimation, robust, median

Can Theil-Sen be defined for multiple linear regression? If so, is there an implementation in R for it?

I simply want a formula `a~b+c`, but the package `mblm` fails with the (misleading) error message: `stop("Only linear models are accepted")`. Of course, this is a linear model: but they mean that Theil-Sen only works for two-dimensional linear models.

Comment: There's more than one way to generalize it. See [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96194/theil-sen-estimation)

Comment: You may also like to consider the answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79869/what-would-be-a-parametric-model-with-properties-similar-to-the-theil-sen-estima)

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate: neither of those include an R implementation

Comment: That part of your post is most likely off-topic instead of a duplicate (see the [help center](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the section under "Programming"). However, the answer at the second link definitely does mention an R package with an implementation for FastS (which isn't really Theil-Sen). I'm not aware of implementations in R for the methods at the first link.